# segmentation fault SIGSEGV

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I am trying to assign the file names in a directory to a 2d array to access them later. I tried to pass a 2d array to the function in every way i knew but i got a segmentation fault each time.

(defined sizes are arbitrary)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <dirent.h>

#define SIZE1 100
#define SIZE2 2500



 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 char tags[100][2500];
 int i;
 char wd[200];
 getcwd(wd,200);
 filestoarray(wd,tags);
 for(i=0;i<40;i++)
 {
    printf("%s",tags);
 }
    
      
      
  return 0;
 }

 void filestoarray(char* basePath,char arr[SIZE1][SIZE2])
  {
     static int i=0;
     char temp[1000];
     char path[1000];
     struct dirent *dp;
     DIR *dir = opendir(basePath);


    if (!dir)
    return;

     while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
     {
         if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") != 0)
         {
            strcpy(path, basePath);
            strcat(path, "\\");
            strcat(path, dp->d_name);
        
            strcpy(arr[i],path); 
            i++;
         }
         filestoarray(path,arr);
    
       }
    closedir(dir);

   }
```

Comment: How can this compile with wrong number of arguments passed to `filestoarray`?

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile, you call `filestoarray` before you declare it and then you pass the wrong number of arguments

Comment: Why are you recursing? Each time you call `opendir` again (and each time `i` will be `0` too, so even if this did "work" you will overwrite the first array element each time).

Comment: i have accidentally deleted the second argument its fixed now(while typing it to stackoverflow)

Comment: No, it still won't compile without a declaration. Please don't "type in your code". Copy/paste it.

Comment: How can I make it so that it doesnt overwrite the array?, I dont know of any other way to get all filenames from a directory

Comment: Stop using recursion?

Comment: Aside: the function should be `int filestoarray` and return the number of elements used. In `main` you have dimension `100` and then guess that there are `40` entries.